# How to extract a negative number from a String?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, uikit

I have a `string` with a math equation which can contain a negative number `"-6-9"`.

I need to extract all numbers from this string and put them into a `numbersArray`:

```
let numbersArray = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+-x/"))
```

Output I need: `["-6", "9"]`

Output I receive: `["", "6", ""]`

I think it's because I have a string with doubled characters. In my case I have two minuses in the string (`-`) and with this minus I am trying to separate the `string`.

How can I separate the numbers in the string properly to receive a desired output?

Comment: The computer is not going to know by magic that the `-` in `-6` has a different status in your mind from the `-` in `-9`. You are going to have to include _logic_ that differentiates them somehow. Writing a math expression parser is a very sophisticated problem! (Unless you want to just take advantage of the capabilities of NSExpression, of course.)

Comment: Maybe require that all operators have spaces around them?

e.g. `-6 - 9` instead of `-6-9`

Comment: @ProgrammerG in my case I receive a string without spaces. Will try to add

Comment: @matt yes, this is why I created the post, because I just learning Swift and can't create a good logic to extract them properly. And didn't find any similar questions also.

Comment: Your post doesn’t make any sense. Why "-6-9" would become "-6" and "9" instead of "-6" and "-9"?

Comment: @LeoDabus sorry, if I was unclear. In my case I will always have an equation like 2+3 or 4-6 as a String, so math symbol between numbers always be a separator. And in case with a negative number I receive 2 equal math signs and can't separate a string by it anymore...

Comment: Why isn't the operator part of the output?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I though of that, but couldn't figure out how to create an output as ["-6", "-", "9"]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with regex, something like this will do:

```
 do {
        let string = "-6-9"
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[\\+\\-][0-9]+")
        let results = regex.matches(in: string,
                                    range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))
        let res = results.map {
            String(string[Range($0.range, in: string)!])
        }
        print(res.compactMap { Int($0) })
    }
    catch {

    }
```

Output:

```
[-6, -9]
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. But what if I need output as [-6, 9]? Separate string by the symbol which is between numbers

Comment: You still need some sort of separator, or if you know for sure that your number will contain one digit change the regex to "[\\+\\-]?[0-9]" And if you need to add a new separate add it to the first brackets with \\ if that is a special symbol